# LightSwitch HTML Client pubished on azure get an 400.0 bad request error

Tags: lightswitch-2013, azure-web-app-service

Well, I have this problem: **"Request failed with status code '400' and the status text 'Bad Request'."** when I run my LightSwitch HTMLClient application that are published in Azure Web Applications.

I already look everywhere for 3 days and still could not find the answer to this problem.

The fiddler throws these:
**NOTICE: Don't follow the links, they are dummies**

GET http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationData.svc/$metadata
400 Bad Request (text/html)

The Request

**GET** /ApplicationData.svc/$metadata HTTP/1.1
**MaxDataServiceVersion:** 3.0
**Accept:** application/xml
**Referer:** http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/HTMLClient/default.htm
**Accept-Language:** es-MX,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
**Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate
**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
**Connection:** Keep-Alive
**Host:** myapp.azurewebsites.net
**Cookie:** ARRAffinity=354b4b5b87b2f1e4e8b6c19a5566c6e055bf3e4047b54b4d2ea846ba1b33d561; msls-client-parameters=preferredLanguage=es-MX; ASP.NET_SessionId=bkf52whz0rkufhcxmqrfuirm

The Response

**HTTP/1.1** 400 Bad Request
**Cache-Control:** private
**Content-Type:** text/html
**Server:** Microsoft-IIS/8.0
**X-AspNet-Version:** 4.0.30319
**X-Content-Type-Options:** nosniff
**X-Powered-By:** ASP.NET
**Date:** Wed, 01 Apr 2015 04:23:39 GMT
**Content-Length:** 1647
**Connection:** Keep-Alive

The azure logs, the lightswitch diagnostic and the debugger not show any difference from these.

I hope someone in this forum can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue, just needed to add references to the bin directory of the application that were not adding.

Thanks.